# activerecord with two similar tables

Tags: c#, interface, abstract-class, castle-activerecord

I have two Tables on my Database. They look like this (it's just a simple example, there are probably mistakes in the code)

```
create table Person
(
   id int,
   name nvarchar(50),
   surname nvarchar(50),
   street nvarchar(50),
   city nvarchar(50)
)

create table Organisation
(
   id int,
   name nvarchar(50),
   contact int Foreign Key Person(Id)
   street nvarchar(50),
   city nvarchar(50)
)
```

Now I want to create my ActiveRecord classes. But about 90% of the columns have the same information. Is there a way to create an abstract ActiveRecord class / Interface where I save my duplicated information? Something like:

```
[ActiveRecord]
public abstract class / interface Customer
{
    [PrimaryKey(Generator = PrimaryKeyType.Identity)]
    long Id { get; set; }

    [Property]
    string name { get; set; }

    [Property]
    string street { get; set; }

    [Property]
    string city { get; set; }
}

[ActiveRecord (Table = "Person")]
public class Person : Customer
{   
    [Property]
    public string surname { get; set; }
}

[ActiveRecord (Table = "Organisation")]
public class Organisation : Customer
{   
    [BelongsTo(Column = "contact", ForeignKey = "FK_Person_Contact")]
    public Person Contact { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my problem:
http://docs.castleproject.org/Active%20Record.Nested%20data%20(NHibernate%20components).ashx